How to setup an SQS listener as part of a FASTAPI app that listens for messages after app startup without blocking endpoints without celery?
I have a fastapi application that has few api endpoints. I need to setup an sqs listener which constantly listens to messages without blocking the endpoints.
There's 2 endpoints in my app - /health and /search. /health is used for healthchecks and /search is used for searching something. I'm trying to move my application to a completely asynchronous system using sqs queues instead of http calls. So I'll have a queue dedicated for search requests. I would still keep the endpoint as an option mainly for testing purposes. So I need this listener to constantly look for messages in the queue.
async def sqs_listener():
  logger.info("Started Listener")
  testQueue = await create_queue("testQueue")
  print(testQueue)

  while(True):
      messages = receive_messages(testQueue, 5, 10)
      print(messages)

And in main.py I tried using lifespan to invoke this listener, but the FastAPI application is not starting and instead the listener is running in an infinite loop, blocking the main event loop, preventing FastAPI from properly initializing and serving requests.
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    listener_task = asyncio.create_task(sqs_listener())
    yield

Looking for a solution that doesn't require celery if possible.

Please post a minimal reproducible example. The issue is most likely that your receive_messages function is synchronous and therefore blocks, but that's impossible to say without seeing the code.

@M.O. Yes the recieve_messages() was synchronous, I made the call in a different thread and that resolved it for me. Thanks..
messages = await asyncio.to_thread(
queue.receive_messages,
MessageAttributeNames=["All"],
MaxNumberOfMessages=max_number,
WaitTimeSeconds=wait_time,
)

A receive_messages method blocks due to WaitTimeSeconds for long polling, so it should be run in another thread to make it non-blocking.
You can easily achieve this using asyncio.to_thread.
Your code is incomplete, so here's the new complete code.
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

import boto3
from fastapi import FastAPI

sqs = boto3.resource("sqs")
queue = sqs.create_queue(QueueName="qqq")

async def long_polling():
    while True:
        messages = await asyncio.to_thread(
            queue.receive_messages,  # <-- blocking task
            MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
            WaitTimeSeconds=20,
        )
        # process messages..


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(_: FastAPI):
    task = asyncio.create_task(long_polling())

    yield

    task.cancel()
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

See how to cancel a task: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel

This is similar to what I've done and works as expected. Thanks for putting this together.
